# Objective C: NSNumber from Array to float

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsnumber

I have an array:

```
SomeArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:50.0],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:120.0],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:200.0],nil];
```

When I retrieve it:

```
NSNumber* Target = [SomeArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

When I NSLog it:

```
NSLog(@"Target %d",Target);
```

it return something funky like

```
2013-06-26 01:47:58.940 KKK[1027:c07] Target 121016880
```

What is the proper way to do this?? I just need the `number` in the array to be used as `float`.

Comment: Use `%@` to log an object. `%d` is for `int`.

Comment: You can specify that entire array like this: `@[@50.0, @120.0, @200.0]`. It's a lot easier to read that way, and it saves us from having to scroll to see your code.

Comment: When you typed in your call to `NSLog`, Xcode probably warned you: “Format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'NSNumber *'”.  You should always pay close attention to compiler warnings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are retrieving a `NSNumber`, which is an object.

`%d` is for logging decimals, which is not your case.

Either you log it with

```
NSLog(@"Target %@", target);
```

or you convert it to a float and use `%f`

```
NSLog(@"Target %f", [target floatValue]);
```

And **PLEASE** don't use capitalized identifiers for variables!

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for a decimal %d in the log and also a primitive type. NSNumber is an object that wraps a primitive type numbers. So you can do like that
`NSLog(@"target %f",[Target floatValue])` or `NSLog(@"target %@",Target)`. With the first you are sending a message to the object to unwrap the float value with the latter you are asking for the object description that in this case is the number

Comment: `%d` is not decimal, it is for `int`.

Comment: @rmaddy Wrong. It **is** decimal. `d` stands for "decimal". There are a number of ways one can print an integer. `x` is for hex, `o` is for octal, etc... Decimal means base-10, it's not necessarily a floating-point number.

Comment: %i is for int, %d is for decimal, but in general use you can mix them

Comment: As far as I know there's no difference at all between `%i` and `%d`, but I'll double check just in case.

Comment: @Andrea When used with `printf()`, `%i` is an obsolescent synonim for `%d`, i. e. it does the same thing as `%d` does, but `%d` is preferred.

Comment: [Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string): *int as a signed decimal number. '%d' and '%i' are synonymous for output, but are different when used with scanf() for input (using %i will interpret a number as hexadecimal if it's preceded by 0x, and octal if it's preceded by 0.)*

Comment: @H2CO3 Maybe `%d` stands for "decimal" but it is used for `int` variables. That is not wrong.

Comment: @rmaddy I think what H2CO3 means is that you can print the decimal representation of a float, using the `%d` format

Comment: @H2CO3 Since we're being pedantic: [C11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) has a specific list of obsolescent features, and `%i` isn't one of them.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella If you try to use a `float` value with `%d` you will likely get garbage. `%d` expects an `int` value.

Comment: @rmaddy I stand corrected